# Python Webscrape HTML to CSV File For Loop

Tags: python, csv, for-loop, beautifulsoup

I am pretty new to Python and am having a hard time with my For loop to extract all web links on a certain site. Here is my code:

```
import requests
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
j= [["Population and Housing Unit Estimates"]] # Title
k= [["Web Links"]] # Column Headings
example_listing='https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/popest.html' #Source
r=requests.get(example_listing) #Grab page source html
html_page=r.text
soup=BeautifulSoup(html_page,'html.parser') #Build Beautiful Soup object to help parse the html
with open('HTMLList.csv','w',newline="") as f: #Choose what you want to grab
    writer=csv.writer(f,delimiter=' ',lineterminator='\r')
    writer.writerows(j)
    writer.writerows(k)
    for link in soup.find_all('a'):
        f.append(link.get('href'))
        if not f:
            ""
        else:
            writer.writerow(f)
f.close()
```

Any help is much appreciated. I really don't know where to go from here. Thanks!

Comment: `f` isn't a list... why are you trying to append to it?

Comment: Can you explain what the desired output is and what you have tried? Also try to make it *just a bit* more minimal (see how to make a [mcve])

Comment: Side Note: if you open a file with a `with` statement, you don’t need to `.close()` it. `with` does it automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are trying to save the URLs from the site into a CSV file - one URL per row. First don't reuse `f`, that is for the file. You can write the link directly to the CSV by enclosing the link in the array `writer.writerow([link.get('href')])`. Hope it is helps. Otherwise, please edit your question and add more details.

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

j= [["Population and Housing Unit Estimates"]] # Title
k= [["Web Links"]] # Column Headings

example_listing='https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/popest.html' #Source
r=requests.get(example_listing) #Grab page source html
html_page=r.text
soup=BeautifulSoup(html_page,'html.parser') #Build Beautiful Soup object to help parse the html
with open('HTMLList.csv','w', newline="") as f: #Choose what you want to grab
    writer=csv.writer(f, delimiter=' ',lineterminator='\r')
    writer.writerows(j)
    writer.writerows(k)
    for link in soup.find_all('a'):
        url = link.get('href')
        if url:
            writer.writerow([url])
```

Comment: Perfect! I just realized that there are a bunch of duplicate URLs. Is there a way to ensure that there are no duplicated links?

Answer (score 1):

```
import requests
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
j= ["Population and Housing Unit Estimates"] # Title
k= ["Web Links"] # Column Headings
example_listing='https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/popest.html' #Source
r=requests.get(example_listing) #Grab page source html
html_page=r.text
soup=BeautifulSoup(html_page,'html.parser') #Build Beautiful Soup object to help parse the html
with open('HTMLList.csv','w',newline="") as f: #Choose what you want to grab
    writer=csv.writer(f,delimiter=' ',lineterminator='\r')
    writer.writerow(j)
    writer.writerow(k)
    for link in soup.find_all('a'):
        if link.get('href') is not None:
            writer.writerow([link.get('href')])
```

HTMLList.csv

```
"Population and Housing Unit Estimates"
"Web Links"
https://www.census.gov/en.html
https://www.census.gov/topics/population/age-and-sex.html
https://www.census.gov/topics/business-economy.html
https://www.census.gov/topics/education.html
https://www.census.gov/topics/preparedness.html
https://www.census.gov/topics/employment.html
https://www.census.gov/topics/families.html
https://www.census.gov/topics/population/migration.html
https://www.census.gov/geography.html
https://www.census.gov/topics/health.html
https://www.census.gov/topics/population/hispanic-origin.html
https://www.census.gov/topics/housing.html
https://www.census.gov/topics/income-poverty.html
https://www.census.gov/topics/international-trade.html
https://www.census.gov/topics/population.html
.......
```

Comment: Perfect! I just realized that there are a bunch of duplicate URLs. Is there a way to ensure that there are no duplicated links?